# giving a window the focus of the application in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, focus, winmain

I am trying to make a simple game in Win32 C++ and I made a settings window that gets called when the user presser the 'P' button or 'Esc'.

Now my question is how can I give that settings window the focus as long as the window is not destroyed, I tried using the `SetFocus();` function and also I tried to send a `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS` Messages by using the `SendMessage();` function and they worked fine but when I press on the main window with the mouse the focus goes to the main window again.

I don't know if my problem had something with the focus but what I am trying to do is to make my settings window like a message box that once it appear you cant click outside it unless you closed it.

Comment: When your application opens a new window, it automatically gets the focus. Don't mess with it, and you'll be fine. There is hardly ever a reason to call `SetFocus`, and you *certainly* should never send `WM_SETFOCUS`/`WM_KILLFOCUS` messages yourself by calling `SendMessage`!

Comment: OK i get it but i want to keep it focused even if the user presses outside this window. is it possible?and how?

Comment: You want a modal dialog. Simple solution is to call `DialogBox` to create and display the dialog. Alternatively, you could disable the main window.

Comment: Also keep in mind that on Windows, "focus" just means "can receive keyboard messages". A control in your dialog window will have the focus at any given time. It will be indicated with a dotted rectangle around it or inside it.

Comment: Dialog box should fix your problem. If you are creating a window then show the code, including the creation flags for the new window.

Comment: ok thanks it worked well now with me

Comment: You should use the `@` character, as in @UserName if you want to get the attention of a specific user who commented on your post. Not everybody revisits the same question. Anyway, your question was headed in the wrong direction...